# #officewriter - Worksheet.PopulatedCells.AutoFitHeight(); not working

Tags: officewriter

#officewriter -    Worksheet.PopulatedCells.AutoFitHeight(); not working.

Recently i have updated excel version from xls to xlsx, but now the above function is not working, giving below error.

Error :  No cells have been populated in the Worksheet

Answer (score 0):

> Populated cells will look for cells with values in them and return an
>   area that includes all the cells. If populated cells have no values
>   then it will thrown an exception, however if that is the case there is
>   nothing to autoFit.
>
> One way to work around this would be to define the area to autofit
>   (say the whole worksheet) and then call autofit. Then you don't have
>   to rely on populated cells to determine the area.